# uploading hello-world program on micaz : programmer is not responding

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, contiki

I have a problem when trying to upload hello-world program to micaz mote.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.contiki-os.org/start.html) to upload `hello-world` program on hardware, but when I tryied to run the command :

```
make hello-world.upload
```

I have this error message :

```
using saved target 'micaz'
avr-objcopy -O srec hello-world.micaz hello-world.srec
uisp -dprog=mib510 -dserial=/dev/ttyS0 -dpart=ATmega128 --wr_fuse_h=0xd1--wr_fuse_e=ff --erase --upload if=hello-world.srec --verify 
make: uisp: Command not found
make: *** [hello-world.upload] Error 127
rm hello-world.srec
```

I think that the problem is that `uisp` command is not installed, so I tryed to install it with :

```
sudo apt-get install uisp
```

Then I had this error message :

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe uisp i386 20050207-4ubuntu1
  Could not connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.13). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/u/uisp/uisp_20050207-4ubuntu1_i386.deb  Could not connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.13). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Is there someone who has uploaded successfully a program on hardware (micaz mote) ?

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
make TARGET=micaz blink.upload PORT=/dev/ttyUSB0   //  connect to PC via MIB520
```

for more information the solution is [here](http://blog.163.com/hairong_yan/blog/static/798129562008416101630542) and [here](http://alan-xuefei.blogspot.fr/2012/05/burn-mote-contiki-tinyos-micaz-telosb.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found how to install uisp command, for those who still have the same problem with installing `uisp`, the solution is [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.os.contiki.devel/3859).

After installing `uisp` I encounter another problem.

When I run :

```
make hello-world.upload
```

I have an error message :

```
using saved target 'micaz'
avr-objcopy -O srec hello-world.micaz hello-world.srec
uisp -dprog=mib510 -dserial=/dev/ttyS0 -dpart=ATmega128 --wr_fuse_h=0xd1 --wr_fuse_e=ff --erase --upload if=hello-world.srec --verify
Programmer is not responding.
make: *** [hello-world.upload] Error 2
rm hello-world.srec
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is you need to install new version of uisp:

```
    $ wget "http://kasun.ch.googlepages.com/uisp.tar.gz"
    $ tar -xvzf uisp.tar.gz
    $ cd uisp
    $ ./bootstrap
    $ ./configure
    $ make
    $ sudo make install
```